# Binding a TextBox's Text Property to TextBlock's Attached Property like Grid.Row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Suppose I have two elements. Lets say,

1. TextBlock
2. TextBox

Now If I want to bind Text of TextBox to the Text of TextBlock I can do something like :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=someTextBlock}" />
```

Now if my TextBlock is inside a Grid as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="someText" Grid.Row=1 Grid.Column=2 />
</Grid>
```

Now my question is how to bind Text of the TextBox to Grid.Row or Grid.Column?

I mean

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Grid.Row, ElementName=someTextBlock} />
```

The above code does not work.

I know I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use this syntax:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Path=(Grid.Row), ElementName=someTextBlock} />
```

This is documented in [Binding.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> To bind to an attached property, place parentheses around the attached property. For example, to bind to the attached property DockPanel.Dock, the syntax is Path=(DockPanel.Dock).

For example, this displays 2 rows, with a `TextBox` containing "1" and a `TextBlock` below:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=(Grid.Row), ElementName=someTextBlock}"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="someTextBlock" Text="Foo" />
</Grid>
```